# How do I change the 0[ins] key to an actual 0?

Tags: keyboard

When I press zero on the number pad it opens the 4 work spaces as a shortcut. How do I change that to zero?

Comment: Num Lock? Usually works...

Answer (score 0):

Is the NumLock light on? If not, go into your BIOS and specify NumLock ON at boot

Comment: Didn't know there is a BIOS setting for Num lock... might vary by system though.